# groovy:lang.MissingPropertyException:No such property: Workbook for class

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am getting this error from my code:

> groovy:lang.MissingPropertyException:No such property: Workbook for
>   class: Script3 error at line:3

```
import jxl.*

def f = new File("E:\\xyz\\data.xls")

def wk = Workbook.getWorkbook(f)

def s1 = wk.getSheet(0)

def rows = s1.getRows()
```

Comment: downloaded jxl and placed in soapui  ext path, can please some one help me , used same code in my personal laptop, it is working,  but the same code in office laptop is not working

Comment: Where is an import to `Workbook` class?

Comment: You'll have to copy the `jxl` jar to your soapUI jar directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use apache poi jar files inside SOAPUI HOME/bin/ext .. And use below code to get the rows:-

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;

def projectPath = context.expand('${projectDir}') //Where your project resides main project properties 
def path = projectPath + "/userInput.xls" //your inputsheet name

FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path)

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)
Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheet("Sheet Name")
int rows = sheet1.getLastRowNum();
log.info(rows)
```

It should print you the number of rows.
Hope, it works for you.